# Searching all databases in environment

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I need to be able to search for SQL objects (logins, etc). With a smaller number of servers, I would connect to them all via a registration group in SSMS and do the search.

Does anyone have a better way with a large number of instances?

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to be able to search by type and name of the object, or just the name? IE will you be specifying the object type on each search?

Comment: Just name. It's really more about querying across a large number of instances without creating a linked server to each instance. I know that I can query against a registration group, but wondered if there was a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SQL Power doc for this .

SQL Power Doc was written by Kendal VanDyke. It is a command line PowerShell manifest consisting of several PowerShell modules that will help you build a solid foundation to Discover, Document and Diagnose SQL Server instances and Windows Operating system details. Additionally, you’ll gain some insight into what directions you can go for future exploration. It basically invokes PowerShell cmdlets and give you the necessary details front and center.

How to use has been described [here](https://www.sqlshack.com/using-sql-power-doc-to-discover-diagnose-and-document-sql-server/)

You can just filter out in the report for the objects you want or even before executing PS you can adjust the parameters as needed.